# Do we need $x>0$ to calculate limit of $\left(\frac{x^n}{2n+1} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: limits

Given that $a_n = \left(\frac{x^n}{2n+1} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ where $x>0$. By simple calculation, it is known that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=x$.

Question: Do we need the condition $x>0$? If I drop it, will our answer be different?

Comment: Are you trying to use the root test?

Comment: if $x < 0 $ the answer is $|x|$

Comment: @OlivierOloa: no, i just evaluate the limit directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have $x<0$, then we have a divergent sequence since for $n=2k$, we get a sequence converging to $|x|$ as $k\to\infty$ while if $n=2k+1$, the sequence converges to $x$.